# Cannot under stand whats happening here

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

The below is an update method, would someone take a try explaining it

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x+10)* Time.deltaTime , 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: you mean except something really strange that shouldn't be used at all? ^^ All your answers will be in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/)

Answer (score 0):

the `Update`-Method is called every frame. In your case the method rotates the transform of the gameobject in an unusual way. You should either manipulate the [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) or [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) the transform by a given value.